# C# + VB: Import reg file

Tags: c#, vb.net, import, registry

There are many answers to this question found here, but they don't seem to work in Win10 for me...
C#

```
string RegFile = "some long path with spaces\file.reg";    
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s \"" + RegFile + "\"");
regeditProcess.WaitForExit();
```

VB

```
Dim RegFile As String = "some long path with spaces\file.reg"
Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s" & Chr(34) & RegFile & Chr(34))
```

Both cases still come up with the Regedit confirmation box despite the /s parameter.

Comment: have you tried running the program with Administrator Privileges?

Comment: I'm running with admin rights. perhaps company policies are influencing this

Comment: I think it would come from UAC could you try to run the code on another computer where the session is admin and the program is ran as admin?

Comment: That's no option. This program needs to be run by a lot of users. I'll have to talk to our IT folks

Comment: then try: `regedit /s` and `reg /s` but if you cant test your code on another computer not sure if it comes from the code or your computer

Comment: reg /s did the trick. Why does this work?

Comment: To be honest i'm not sure the reason i'' write a detailed answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be coming from the UAC and not having the proper rights to launch the registry in silent mode.

It might also have been the fact that the **regedit.exe** file might have been modified or changed during some install processes.

Recommendations:

- Run the program as admin

You should also try:

```
Process.Start("regedit", "/s" & Chr(34) & RegFile & Chr(34))
```

And

```
Process.Start("reg", "/s" & Chr(34) & RegFile & Chr(34))
```

I think this should call directly the reference of the program from windows which might link to another .exe and hence this is why it could work with this version.

If anoyone else knows why the `reg /s` option works but not the others please let me know as well.